# Install Bulma in Laravel 9

Tags: npm-scripts, bulma, laravel-9

I already have a project in Laravel 9. I want to convert the UI to use Bulma. I don't want to use the CDN. I've read the documentation about doing it in an older version of Laravel as well as a new install. I want to know how to add Bulma to an existing Laravel 9 application. Note I couldn't find an app.scss file in laravel. So far, I've run the following commands.

```
npm install bulma --save-dev
```

Created an app.scss file in the resources folder and added the following.

```
@import '~bulma/bulma';
```

However, I get the following error. What am I doing wrong? Unfortunately, there is scant documentation on it.

> node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass:1 @charset "utf-8" ^
>
> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at Object.compileFunction
> (node:vm:352:18) at wrapSafe
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15) at Module._compile
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27) at
> Object.Module._extensions..js
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:10) at Module.load
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32) at Function.Module._load
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12) at Module.require
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19) at require
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18) at Object.
> (/home/zeenux/Programming/php/blog/webpack.mix.js:17:9) at
> Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)

Answer (score 3):

This is how i tried it and it works fine, no issue with bulma

First

```
npm install bulma
```

Then in **resources/css/app.css**

```
@import 'bulma/css/bulma.min.css';
```

in blade

```
<head>
  .....
  <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <button class="button is-primary">
      Button
   </button>
</body>
```

Now i have tried your way with sass

in **resources/sass/app.scss**

```
//@import '~bulma/bulma';
   BOTH WORKS FINE
//@import 'bulma/css/bulma.min.css';
```

webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    //.css('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

So all works fine to me, what you are facing is probably npm version issue
i am using 8.5.3 to install that run this `npm install -g npm@8.5.3`. **Please do keep in mind while playing with npm versions, install only that npm version which is compatable with all of your packages you are using in your project.**